# How to group together certain answers in a Category in R

Tags: r

So in this dataframe one of my variables "ecoact" has 4 possibilities "Economically inactive", "Full-time working", "Part-time working" and "Unemployed and work related Government Training Programmes"

I want to group 3 of them together ("Full-time working", "Part-time working" and "Unemployed and work related Government Training Programmes") so that I end up with only 2 possibilities "Economically inactive" or "Economically active".

I've looked for ways to do this, but couldn't find anything or couldnt applied to what I want to do.

Comment: `(df$ecoact=="Economically inactive")` will define your two categories (as `TRUE` or `FALSE` values).

Answer (score 1):

If your variable class is char, then you can simply create a new variable with an `ifelse()`statement. If it's a factor, you should be careful and transform on-the-fly your type with `as.characater.factor()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your vector is a factor you can use the recode function in library Car.

```
> library('car')
> x <- factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C" ,"D"), 3))
> x
 [1] A B C D A B C D A B C D
 Levels: A B C D
> recode(x, " c('A') = 'Economic Active'; c('B','C','D') = 'Economic 
  Inactive';")
  [1] Economic Active   Economic Inactive Economic Inactive Economic Inactive 
      Economic Active   Economic Inactive
  [7] Economic Inactive Economic Inactive Economic Active   Economic Inactive 
      Economic Inactive Economic Inactive
      Levels: Economic Active Economic Inactive
```